# Value of type 'NSFetchRequestResult' has no member 'valueForKeyPath'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I opened my `Swift` project from `Xcode` 7.3 in `Xcode` 8. When the dialog for `Swift` conversion to 3 appeared, I clicked Later. I don't want to update it yet.

I also have `Xcode` 7.3 installed. I am supposed to use it but my iphone has ios 10 already so I won't be able to run it on my phone (developer image not found). I even copied the folder of `iOS10` to my `Xcode` 7.3's files, but still same error.

So I guess, I don't have any choice to use the newest `Xcode` version 8. Just like what i said I didn't convert it to the latest syntax and set all build settings to use legacy `Swift` to `true`.

But I am getting an error here (`MasterViewController.swift`):

```
func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = object.valueForKeyPath("timeStamp")!.description

    }
```

Is this suppose to be working here since I didn't changed/upgraded the syntax?

This conversion to another version of `Swift` is really time consuming and a bit annoying.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `valueForKeyPath` for a one-level key rather than `valueForKey`?